# Run canberra-gtk-play from crontab

Tags: linux, audio, cron

I would like to run the following command through crontab:

`30 12 * * *    natasha    /usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --file="/home/natasha/Audio/Dat_Jene_Tabletki.wav" --volume=15 --loop=3`

but this command isn't executed. Run of the corresponding command directly from command line works.

The lines

`4 12 * * *     natasha /usr/bin/cvlc /home/natasha/Audio/Dat_Jene_Tabletki.wav
55 16 * * *     natasha /usr/local/bin/mpg123 -q /home/natasha/Downloads/file.mp3`

are executed correctly with crontab, but canberra-gtk-play doesn't work.

Could somebody help me with this, please?

My system is openSUSE 42.1.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Natalia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

canberra-gtk-play doesn't work from cron because, as its name says, it depends on the GTK+ graphical toolkit – which requires Xorg or another X11 or Wayland server to be accessible.

Cron jobs don't have easy access to X11 because the server's address isn't always the same – you can try setting `DISPLAY=":0"` and likewise `XAUTHORITY=…`, but they might be different after a reboot.

In contrast, the PulseAudio sound service's address is always at a fixed location, and on systems which don't use PA it's just a matter of accessing /dev directly.

(If you happen to be running Wayland, then canberra-gtk-play should be able to connect to it, but.)

---

I would suggest forgetting `canberra-gtk-play` because... if all you want is to play a sound, *why* would you even bother with tools which require X11?

A better option would be **`paplay`** or `mpv` or even `mplayer`.

Comment: Thank you! I have succeeded to do this using paplay. The reason to use canberra-gtk-play was the ability to set volume manually. paplay can do this as well, while looping may be organized with script.